# Pandas replace integer to empty string (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace column integer values to empty strings (''). But, can not find appropriate way.

```
Current data     

     0
0  asd
1  9
2  gfs
3  45
4  4
5  dsf

Expected result

     0
0  asd
1  
2  gfs
3  
4  
5  dsf
```

Comment: Only integers, or any numeric-like values?

Comment: Yes, I want only string values on my data. Other values need to change to empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) and [`df.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
>>> series
0    asd
1      9
2    gfs
3     45
4      4
5    dsf
Name: 0, dtype: object

>>> series.where(~series.str.isnumeric(), '')
0    asd
1       
2    gfs
3       
4       
5    dsf
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

If it's a dataframe, then:

```
>>> df.where(~df['0'].str.isnumeric(), '')
     0
0  asd
1     
2  gfs
3     
4     
5  dsf
```